# How to load spacy language model from local machine?

Tags: spacy, tokenize, language-model

Since the server I use is not connected to the Internet, I would need to load model from the local disk.

For example, I should be able to run the following code,

```
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
my_language = get_tokenizer('spacy', language='en_core_web_md')
```

I have downloaded en_core_web_md-3.1.0.tar.gz and extracted into the local folder. Then tried adding path_to_folder. It didn't work and says,

```
OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from Sig_Data/en_core_web_md-3.1.0/config.cfg
```

Which makes sense as the folder does NOT have this file.

Then, I have installed en_core_web_md using pip install. I can import it as

```
import en_core_web_md
```

But not sure how can I use it in the context of

```
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
my_language = get_tokenizer('spacy', language='en_core_web_md')
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have downloaded en_core_web_md-3.1.0.tar.gz and extracted into the local folder. Then tried adding path_to_folder. It didn't work and says,

It looks like you used the wrong directory, see the [official docs](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual) for this.

The correct directory after unzipping the model is the directory that doesn't have the version number in it.

Also, not clear if this is what you did when you mention pip install or not, but you should be able to pip install the directory with the `setup.py` file.

> import en_core_web_md

You can do that, but it's not really designed to be used that way. It's expected you'll use `spacy.load`.

> But not sure how can I use it in the context of

That should just work. Do you get an error?